# Protractor tests find no injector in my app, but only on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, protractor

I see this error sporadically, only on Jenkins, but at least once a test run. If I'm lucky it'll just not happen every 5 or 6 builds:

```
    Error: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "root element ([ng-app]) has no injector. this may mean it is not inside ng-app."
      at Error (<anonymous>)
      at /home/tester/workspace/EncoreUI_Template_PR_Builder/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1526:15
      at newFrame.onAbort (/home/tester/workspace/EncoreUI_Template_PR_Builder/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1679:7)
      at [object Object].webdriver.promise.Frame_.notify_ (/home/tester/workspace/EncoreUI_Template_PR_Builder/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1914:5)
      at [object Object]._onTimeout (/home/tester/workspace/EncoreUI_Template_PR_Builder/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1887:13)
      at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)
  ==== async task ====
  Protractor.waitForAngular()
      at [object Object].webdriver.WebDriver.schedule (/home/tester/workspace/EncoreUI_Template_PR_Builder/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:345:15)
      at [object Object].Protractor.executeAsyncScript_ (/home/tester/workspace/EncoreUI_Template_PR_Builder/node_modules/protractor/lib/protractor.js:251:26)
      at [object Object].Protractor.waitForAngular (/home/tester/workspace/EncoreUI_Template_PR_Builder/node_modules/protractor/lib/protractor.js:274:15)
      at [object Object].to.(anonymous function) [as getCurrentUrl] (/home/tester/workspace/EncoreUI_Template_PR_Builder/node_modules/protractor/lib/protractor.js:60:7)
      at Context.<anonymous> (/home/tester/workspace/EncoreUI_Template_PR_Builder/test/stories/loggingIn.js:37:32)
      at /home/tester/workspace/EncoreUI_Template_PR_Builder/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/testing/index.js:121:22
      at [object Object].webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runInNewFrame_ (/home/tester/workspace/EncoreUI_Template_PR_Builder/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1654:20)
      at [object Object].webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runEventLoop_ (/home/tester/workspace/EncoreUI_Template_PR_Builder/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1518:8)
      at [object Object].wrapper [as _onTimeout] (timers.js:258:14)
  ==== async task ====
      at Context.ret (/home/tester/workspace/EncoreUI_Template_PR_Builder/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/testing/index.js:119:12)
      at Test.Runnable.run (/home/tester/workspace/EncoreUI_Template_PR_Builder/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:218:15)
      at Runner.runTest (/home/tester/workspace/EncoreUI_Template_PR_Builder/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:374:10)
      at /home/tester/workspace/EncoreUI_Template_PR_Builder/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:452:12
      at next (/home/tester/workspace/EncoreUI_Template_PR_Builder/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:299:14)
      at /home/tester/workspace/EncoreUI_Template_PR_Builder/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:309:7
      at next (/home/tester/workspace/EncoreUI_Template_PR_Builder/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:248:23)
      at Object._onImmediate (/home/tester/workspace/EncoreUI_Template_PR_Builder/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:276:5)
      at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:336:15)
```

I'm seeing errors that don't appear to happen in either local runs of my tests, or on Travis. But, on a Jenkins slave running firefox, xvfb and Protractor 1.7.0, I'm getting this error quite frequently. At least once a test.

I've updated my conf file to point to '[ng-app]' as my rootElement.

I see in [the angular `getTestability` docs](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/63db09753ef6c46cc63e7c523ff41d9f959dfcdd/docs/content/error/ng/test.ngdoc) that it is thrown "often because the root element is outside of the ng-app", but in this case the selector comes back OK, so I'm wondering what some other reasons why the root element wouldn't have an injector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was two parts. One, Jenkins runs on a VM, and has a less CPU power and network connection speed than my local machine, which explains why it never appeared locally. The second part had to do with the architecture of the app under test. Normally, an Angular app is designed to function as a single page app, where the app that I'm testing is actually a collection of single page apps, tied together via proxies. It gives the illusion that it is one large app, while remaining modular and easier to iterate on.

The problem arises when logging into the app. The Angular app logs you in, proxies to a redirect, and in the process has a "white flash" where nothing is happening. It's at this point where Protractor calls waitForAngular, which asserts that an injector is present in your app before continuing.

This is the part where things get a little strange. According to the commit logs, [a typo in a critical check for an injector](https://github.com/angular/protractor/commit/99eb0fd225f135a3ef66e3e8c9ce39b41a6708c7) may have prevented any issues from occurring in previous versions of Protractor, and so when upgrading, triggered this behavior in environments that run slow enough to occasionally trigger a race condition in the browser. I'm not exactly sure. But in any case, this code in my login page object helped clear up the problem.

```
login: {
    value: function (username, password) {
        // normal login code
        // by now, it has attempted to log in and redirect, and now...
        browser.wait(function () {
            return browser.waitForAngular().then(function () {
                // injector found, everything is ok
                return true;
            }, function () {
                // if any error occurred, don't throw an exception
                // give `.wait` a false result to trigger a retry
                return false;
            });
        }, 10000, 'Injector never appeared after 10 seconds.');
    }
}
```

So, if your system contains many Angular apps strung together via proxy, you can experience the odd error when being passed from one app to the next in environments with a slow CPU and/or limited network connectivity during your Protractor tests.